# How to Re-build HAL in android?

Tags: android, linux, compilation, hal, android-kernel

I have made changes in device//manifest.xml and now i want to rebuild only boot.img and vendor.img.

Is there any way/command to build only HAL module in android ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build single modules or images by providing build targets to `make`.

- Build the boot image: `make bootimage`
- Build the vendor image: `make vendorimage`
  This will build the boot image as well.
- Build a single HAL (e.g. the Power HAL): `make android.hardware.power@1.3`
  **Note:** This will not update the `vendor.img`.

You can get a list of all known build targets with `make modules`.

Answer (score 0):

To build only HAL module in android

Change directory to HAL module where `Android.mk` of HAL is located and give **"mm"** command. My HAL firectory is

```
~/var_imx-android-11.0.0_1.0.0/android_build/vendor/nxp-opensource/imx/libcamera3
```

you can find output of your HAL as **.so** file inside

```
~/var_imx-android-11.0.0_1.0.0/android_build/out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/vendor/lib/hw
```