# how to re-build vendor.img with new changes?

Tags: android, android-source

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272666/how-to-re-build-hal-in-android/58283060#58283060) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829117/how-to-change-vendor-img-contents-with-android-emulator/69904420#69904420) but it doesn't help. It generates the vendor.img but without my the new changes pulled in.

Following is what I've tried,

1. I have build a fresh android images successfully.
2. I have made some changes in aosp/vendor/customer/rootdir/
3. `make vendorimage`

It regenerates the vendor.img but flashing that on the device doesn't show my new changes. Looks like I'm missing something.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Does it happen on a clean build also? Try to build it this way otherwise:
make installclean && make vendorimage

Comment: Have you tried `make clobber` and then `m`?